# Get value of another field in Field level Validation in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using `Field level Validation` in my serializer and I have situation where I need value of first field while validating second field. I know in `object level validation` I can have access to that but my serailzer have `many=True` and in object level validation  I cannot tell client side which iteration have raised the error.

**Serailzer :**

```
class Keys_Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    """
    key_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    key_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    value_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    def validate_key_id(self, value):
        """
        validate key id
        """
         *** validate key_id here ***
        return value

    def validate_value_id(self, value):
        """
        validate value_id w.r.t key_id
        """
         *** I need key_id of current iteration here so that I can validate value_id. ***
        return value
```

Is there any way of accessing the value of key_id in value_id validation.

Comment: which version of Django Rest Framework are you using ?

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib djangorestframework==3.2.2

Comment: can you try accessing using self.otherfieldname and then validate ? 
in DRF version <3 there is a parameter name `attrs` with the each field level validate method and then you can simply access the other values using `attr['field_name']`. But i am not sure how to do this in version >3

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib no there is `attrs` parms in > 3 .

Comment: did you try using self.field_name ?

Comment: yes , I did but no success. Also it is not a Modelserializer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No that is not possible. If you need to access more than one value you have to use the `Object-level validation` ([see docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation)):

```
class Keys_Serializer(serializers.Serializer):

    key_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    key_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    value_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

    def validate(self, data):
        # here you can access all values
        key_id = data['key_id']
        value_id = data['value_id']
        # perform you validation
        if key_id != value_id:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("key_id must be equal to value_id")
        return data
```

Comment: Yes , I know I can access that in object level validation and why I can't use that is mentioned in my question. So I was just wondering if there is any hook or something else with which I can access other values ?

Comment: @Wtower, actually you can, though it is not mentioned in docs. I dug around the codebase of drf a little bit. You can easily access all field values using self.get_initial(). You can look for my answer.

Comment: @user5594493, yes there is a hook. See my answer.

Comment: the solution offered does not work if 'many=True' is specified.

Answer (score 13):

I dug around codebase of drf a little bit. You can get values of all fields using following approach. This way you can throw serialization error as `{'my_field':'error message}` instead of `{'non_field_error':'error message'}`

```
def validate_myfield(self, value):
   data = self.get_initial() # data for all the fields
   #do your validation
```

However, if you wish to do it for `ListSerializer`, i.e for `serializer = serializer_class(many=True)`, this won't work. You will get list of empty values. In that scenario, you could write your validations in `def validate` function and to avoid `non_field_errors` in your serialization error, you can raise `ValidationError` with error message as a dictionary instead of string.

```
def validate(self, data):
    # do your validation
    raise serializers.ValidationError({"your_field": "error_message"})
```

Comment: Doesn't work in 3.11.1 anymore. All values are empty.

Comment: Working fine in 3.12.2.

Comment: Yes, the reason why this approach is better, is the way the error is being thrown; as field_error instead of non_field_error

Answer (score 1):

```py
def validate(self, validated_data):
        """
        validate and verifies the user data before getting saved.
        :param validated_data: dict obj
        :return: validated_data
        """

        existing_data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you're performing a create or update the plain unvalidated data can accessed in:

```
self.context['view'].get_serializer().data
```

Although the other solutions are in fact cleaner, we have a single model on a partitioned table and need another field that specifies the partition, since we're not partitioned on the primary key the database has no clue how to look it up.

EDIT: It appears that field is actually blank, you may have luck with the following, depending on how the Serializer is used (for this it must be used in a ViewSet)

```
self.context['view'].get_serializer().context['request'].data
```

Answer (score 0):

One other simple solution is accessing the properties as below

```
class Keys_Serializer(serializers.Serializer):

key_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
key_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
value_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)

def validate_key_name(self, value):
    #getting other field values as below
    self.initialdata
    #scrape data from initialdata
    # incase of updation time use 
    # self.instance and self.inistialdata together to get respective ones
    return  value
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I just needed other values for the output, not for validation but this could probably be a good starting point. It is based on https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#examples.

You need to override the get_attribute function to return the object instead of  the attribute. From the docs:

```
class ClassNameField(serializers.Field):
def get_attribute(self, instance):
    # We pass the object instance onto `to_representation`,
    # not just the field attribute.
    return instance
```

Then I was able to do stuff like

```
def to_representation(self, instance):  # pylint: disable=arguments-renamed
    return instance.my_function()
    or 
    return f"{instance.attribute_1}, {instance.attribute_2}"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def validate_fieldname(self, value):
   data = self.context['request'].data
```